# JavaScript get recognize button to click

Tags: javascript, button

I am making a Chrome extension and I need this button to be clicked so how can I get the click to be recognized?

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-bet" onclick="system.play.bet.red();">RED</button>
```

I tried `var test= document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-black btn-bet");
test.click();`

but it fails at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document.getElementsByClassName()` [returns an array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) of all child elements which have all of the given class names. Unfortunately, it's not a true JS array. To work with it, you need to "Arrayify" it:

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var testDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function(testElement){
    return testElement.nodeName === 'DIV';
});
```

In your case, this should work:

```
var test= document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-black btn-bet")[0];
test.click();
```